# Where is it allowed to change \hsize?

Tags: plain-tex

In chapter 23 "Output routines" there is a warning:

> It's best not to monkey with \hsize and \vsize except at the very beginning of a job, or after you have ejected all pages from TeX's memory.

But in *TeXbook* itself there are several examples where `\hsize` is changed:

1) In the exercise with story.tex \hsize is set several times in one tex job.

```
\hsize=4in \input story
\hsize=3in \input story
...
```

I suppose, this case is "legal", because `\eject` is called at the end of story.tex

Some more examples:

2) On page 115 `\hsize` is set inside `\topinsert`.

3) On page 223 `\hsize` is set inside `\vbox`.

In which contexts is it "legal" to modify `\hsize` and why there is this warning in *TeXbook*? Is there an example which shows what can go wrong if we change `\hsize` in a "bad" place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What is `\hsize`?

The primitive parameter `\hsize` is the length that TeX uses to split paragraphs into lines (taking also into account `\leftskip`, `\rightskip` and the paragraph shape instructions coming from `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`.

When a paragraph has been split into lines, TeX will contribute a stack of horizontal boxes of width `\hsize` to the current vertical list. The width will be different if `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` are being used and will reflect the actual width of each line.

<sup>When `\parshape` is being used, it's like a different `\hsize` is specified for each line.</sup>

Consider the code

```
\input plipsum

\hsize=300pt

\showboxbreadth=1000 \showboxdepth=0 

\lipsum{1}

\showlists

\hsize=200pt

\lipsum{2}

\showlists

\bye
```

The first `\showlists` command outputs

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\glue(\topskip) 3.05556
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set - 0.62798 []
\penalty 150
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 0.38911 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set - 0.17653 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 0.24695 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 0.36536 []
\penalty 150
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 227.0554fil []
total height 70.0
 goal height 643.20255
prevdepth 1.94444, prevgraf 6 lines
```

so we see a paragraph consisting of six lines, corresponding to six boxes 300pt wide.

The second `\showlists` instruction outputs

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\glue(\topskip) 3.05556
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set - 0.62798 []
\penalty 150
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 0.38911 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set - 0.17653 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 0.24695 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 0.36536 []
\penalty 150
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x300.0, glue set 227.0554fil []
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x200.0, glue set 0.68265 []
\penalty 250
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x200.0, glue set - 0.56822 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x200.0, glue set 0.02776 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x200.0, glue set 0.76903 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x200.0, glue set 1.07141 []
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x200.0, glue set 0.93843 []
\penalty 100
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x200.0, glue set 0.1729 []
\penalty 100
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x200.0, glue set 0.93886 []
\penalty 250
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.75002
\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x200.0, glue set 179.41664fil []
total height 178.0 plus 1.0
 goal height 643.20255
prevdepth 0.0, prevgraf 9 lines
```

The first six lines are there, look for `\parskip` in order to see where the second paragraph starts. We have nine lines, all 200pt wide.

### Where is it legal to change `\hsize`?

Anywhere. Unless `\parshape` is being used, TeX will use the value of `\hsize` which was current when `\par` has been scanned for breaking paragraphs into lines.

Of course, this setting of `\hsize` will respect TeX grouping (if you're not devious enough to do global settings). So if we try

```
{\hsize=1pt \nopar\lipsum{1}}\par
```

we get exactly the same as before, because the change to `\hsize` will have been forgotten when `\par` is found. Note that you cannot have two distinct values for `\hsize` when a paragraph is being built (barring `\parshape`, of course).

### Does `\hsize` influence page shape?

Not by design of TeX. However, the output routine can and probably will use the standard `\hsize` for setting headers and footers. For instance, `\plainoutput` has `\makeheadline` that does

```
\line{\vbox to 8.5pt{}\the\headline}
```

and `\line` is `\hbox to \hsize`.

So this is the main meaning of Knuth's warning: if you change `\hsize` in the middle of a page, unexpected results can show up, depending on when the output routine comes into action.

Changing `\hsize` inside a `\vbox` is always safe, because excercising the page builder when working in a secondary vertical list never calls the output routine.